# Writing to CSV database file from php application

Tags: php, javascript, html, csv

I have a simple **PHP/HTML** application (hosted on Heroku) which runs a survey. I would like to save the responses to this survey (only 4/5 questions) to a **CSV** file for later analysis. These responses are currently saved as **PHP** variables so a form submission is not possible at the moment.

What is the best way to do this? I'm assuming this would be easiest using Javascript but am open to suggestions. Also, should I put the **CSV** file on a different server?

Comment: Use [PHP `file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php): client side JS cannot save a file on the server.

Comment: or better, use [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/fputcsv)

Comment: With the **CSV** file just with the other files on the same server? Then what's the easiest way to test it?

Comment: Also, is the call of a **PHP** function possible server side?